# Calculation of Dependent Values in Java

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, graph-algorithm

Using Java, I've got a source data set of integers, it's big but not huge - let's say it won't get bigger than 30,000 values.

Using the source dataset I have some summary values I want to create (these are domain specific so not something you'll find in a library such as Apache Math).

There is a relationship between the summary values like this:

```
[source data] -> summary1 -> summary2 -> summary3
                     \                     ^
                      \____________________|
```

I don't want to over-engineer the solution, but I do expect in future that there may be additional summary values that will build upon this graph. Currently my solution involves having a domain object that has a 'getter' for each summary and merely checks if it has already been computed, and compute-stores it if needed. This works fine, but I don't like having all this compute logic in my domain object.

It feels to me like this could be represented as more of a key->calculator design where results are stored in a map and calculators know which "keys" they need. Before I go off and implement something like this it's very hard to imagine someone hasn't already done this (a thousand times).

Can anyone advise me on idioms or any libraries that would be worth looking at for this kind of problem space? I'm familiar with things like JGraph but I don't believe this will let me associate a calculator on a node, it will merely provide a graph model. Perhaps this is more problem for a caching library?

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem that you're having, however the latest version of Guava implemented the Graph type which, I recommend looking into.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd put Guava's graph in the same category as JGraph - it provides a graph data structure rather than the caching/evaluation of a graph which I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

The `key -> calculator` idea looks like a typical application of a loading cache (aka auto populating, aka read through). An example to do it with [cache2k](https://cache2k.org):

```
  Cache<Key, Integer> summary1cache = new Cache2kBuilder<Key, Integer>() {}
    .loader(this::calculateSummary1)
    .build();

  int calculateSummary1(Key key) {
    ...
  }
```

To achieve the best performance I recommend one cache per summary type. The user guide has more information about [cache loaders / read through](https://cache2k.org/docs/1.0/user-guide.html#loading-read-through).

You can do exactly the same with other caches, e.g. Guava Cache or Caffeine.

An alternative pattern is `Map.computeIfAbsent(key, function)`. However, if the loader function is known from the start I recommend configuring the cache with it.

Disclaimer: I don't know for 100% whether this is the best solution since it is not totally clear from the question how many different keys / summaries you'll have and what the access pattern looks like.

Comment: Thanks @cruftex. I should have clarified; I don't think there will be more than 10 summaries. Access pattern will be update infrequent (base data is pretty much fixed although could be edited in theory), reads will also be low - maybe max 10/min as will be displayed in a single user UI. A cache isn't needed for performance here, but the pattern of key to calculator would break up the calculation graph nicely.